# subprocess.Popen.send_signal(CTRL_C_EVENT) does not work

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a piece of python code that should spawn an interruptible task in a child process:

```
class Script:
    '''
    Class instantiated by the parent process
    '''

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.process = None
        self.start()

    def __del__(self):
        if self.process:
            if self.process.poll() is None:
                self.stop()

    def start(self):
        popen_kwargs = {
            'executable': sys.executable,
            'creationflags': 0 * subprocess.CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE
                           | subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP,
        }
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(['python', os.path.realpath(__file__)],
                                        **popen_kwargs)

    def stop(self):
        if not self.process:
            return
        try:
            self.process.send_signal(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
            self.process.wait()
            self.process = None
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass



class ScriptSubprocess:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stop = False

    def run(self):
        try:
            while not self.stop:
                # ...
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            # interrupted!
            pass
        finally:
            # make a *clean* exit if interrupted
            self.stop = True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = ScriptSubprocess()
    p.run()
    del p
```

and it works fine in a standalone python interpreter.

The problem arises when I move this code in the real application, which has an embedded Python interpreter.
In this case, it hangs when trying to stop the child process at the line `self.process.wait()`, indicating the previous line `self.process.send_signal(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)` did not work and in fact the child process is still running and if I manually terminate it via task manager, the call to `self.process.wait()` returns as if it has succeeded stopping the child process.

I am looking for possible causes (e.g. some process flag of the parent process) that disables CTRL_C_EVENT.

The documentation of subprocess says:

> `Popen.send_signal(signal)`
>
> Sends the signal signal to the child.
>
> Do nothing if the process completed.
>
> Note On Windows, SIGTERM is an alias for `terminate()`. CTRL_C_EVENT and
> CTRL_BREAK_EVENT can be sent to processes started with a creationflags
> parameter which includes CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP.

and also:

> `subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`
>
> A Popen creationflags parameter to specify that a new process group will be created. This flag is necessary for using `os.kill()` on the subprocess.
>
> This flag is ignored if CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE is specified.

So I am using `creationflags` with `subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`, but still it is unable to kill the subprocess with CTRL_C_EVENT in the real application. (same as without this flag)

Since the real application (i.e. the parent process) is also using [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler) to handle certain signals, I also try to pass `creationflags` with `subprocess.CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE` to override that error mode in the child process, but still unable to kill the child process with CTRL_C_EVENT.

Note: CTRL_BREAK_EVENT works but does not give a clean exit (i.e. the `finally:` clause is not executed).

My guess is that `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` is the culprit, but I have no means of avoiding that being called in the parent process, or undoing its effect...

Comment: 1) why is `CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE` multiplied by 0? 2) is there a reason for not using Popen.terminate?

Comment: You might want to make an MVP.

Comment: 1: any combination of CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE and/or CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP gives me the same result, i.e. send_signal(CTRL_C_EVENT) ignored

Comment: 2: terminate() would not do a "clean" exit (i.e. call exit handlers, execute `finally:` clause, ...) so it is the same as send_signal(CTRL_BREAK_EVENT) which also works